# Unable to query using the dynamic id field in function(req, res, next, id) mongoose ( mongodb )

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mean-stack

I'm using mean js,  I'm trying to query mongodb via a Service call in angularjs,

```
   var Priority = 'Left_VM_P'; 
   url = currentUrl+"/api/queryPrioritySearch/"+Priority;
```

the query works only when

```
Property.find({ Left_VM_P : true }).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

when i try to replace the variable Left_VM_P with the value of the id,  it doesn't respond.

```
exports.queryPrioritySearch = function(req, res, next, id) { 
console.log('id = ', id); 
Property.find({ id : true }).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

Upon console logging
the value of id comes to be

```
id =  Left_VM_P
```

Here's the sample mongo object.

```
    { 
      "Left_VM_P": true,
      "Later_P": true,
      "High_P": true,
      "last_date_call_was_made": "-",
      "call_priority": "-"
    }
```

Also when I search in the mongo shell it returns value correctly.

```
> db.properties.find({"Left_VM_P" : true}).count();
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can not put variable on left side of mongodb query. mongodb always consider left side as field name as string. so

```
Property.find({ Left_VM_P : true }).exec(function(err, properties)
```

will work because it consider left_VM_P as string so it is like `"Left_VM_P": true`

in case of `Property.find({ id : true })` it is taking it as string `"id":true`

but you want dynamic name in place of id so you can try this solution

```
var dynamicId={};
dynamicId[id]=true;
Property.find(dynamicId).exec(function(err, properties)
```

i hope this will help :)

Here's the full version:

```
exports.queryPrioritySearch = function(req, res, next, id) { 
var id_2  = id; 

var dynamicId={};
dynamicId[id_2]=true;


Property.find(dynamicId).exec(function(err, properties) {
```